# Conocer filas tienen másde un valor NaN

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un dataframe al cual quiero saber que filas tienen más de un valor NaN/None/NaT entre todas sus columnas. Es decir, si yo hago

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1)
```

Se si esa fila tiene alguna columna con NaN, pero ¿Si quiere saber las que tienen más de una columna?

Aplicando

```
a = df.isnull().sum()
print (a[a>0])
```

Me sale lo siguiente:

```
Col3  16
Col5   7
Col12  3
dtype: int64
```

Que creo que es la cantidad de filas que tienen NaN/None/NaT cada columna pero yo no quiero eso, quiero que si por ejemplo la fila 2 solo tiene un NaN en la columna 3, la omita, pero que si tiene 2 o más NaN entre las diferentes columnas sí que me la diga.

También he probado esto

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1).sum()
```

Pero no sé que hace :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya que `df.isnull()` devuelve un dataframe lleno de booleanos (`True` en las celdas que eran NaN), lo que queremos en realidad es contar, ya sea por filas o por columnas, cuántos de esos valores son `True`.

Podemos usar la función `sum()` para sumar por columnas (o `sum(axis=1)` para sumar por filas). La suma de booleanos se *forzará* a enteros, considerando `True` como 1 y `False` como 0. Por tanto el resultado será el número de `True`.

```
a = df.isnull().sum()        # Resultado por columnas
a = df.isnull().sum(axis=1)  # Resultado por filas
```

Ahora ya podemos quedarnos sólo con las columnas o filas que tengan un contador mayor de 1:

```
print(a[a>1])
```

**Nota** Aunque pandas tiene un método `.count()`, no nos sirve, ya que no es para contar el número de `True`, sino el número de valores que hay (distintos de NaN). Por tanto `df.isnull().count()` daría el mismo número para todas las columnas, pues todas tienen el mismo número de elementos no-nulos, ya que todos son `True` o `False`.

### Adicionalmente

Lo que habías hecho:

```
df.isnull().any(axis=1).sum()
```

te devuelve cuántas filas tienen algún `NaN`. Se interpreta de la siguiente forma:

- `df.isnull()` te retorna un dataframe de iguales  dimensiones que el original, pero con `True` donde había `NaN` y `False` en el resto.
- aplicar `.any(axis=1)` te retorna una Serie con tantas filas como tenía `df.isnull()`, y en cada fila un `True` si había algún `True` en esa fila, o `False` si no había ninguno. Es decir, `True` para las filas que tenían un `NaN` en `df`.
- aplicar `.sum()` a esa Serie, suma todos los `True` que hay en ella (ya que se consideran 1 y los `False` 0). Por tanto el resultado será el número de `True` que había, es decir, el número de filas que tenían algún `NaN` en `df`.